# How can I attach bottom bar to top of bottom sheet?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom container with a progress bar in it, and when i click or swipe up i need it to follow the bottom sheet as a header.
Can I attach it to the bottom sheet or can I implement it in the sheet itself and then have the sheet peek up by some offset?

I've watched all guides, tutorials and flutter demos of the first few google pages and I cant seam to find any information about it.

Please provide me some guidance so I can flutter in the right direction.

Comment: It'll be easier to get help if you show some code with what you have or what you tried, and why it doesn't work the way you expect. Perhaps also an image of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect can be achieved using some basic widget building.

```
StackView
  Container: background overlay
  Column: MainAxisSize.max
    Container: height = (screenHeight - bottomBarHeight)
    BottomBar: fixes size
    Container: Bottom Dialog
```

Create a fullscreen stateful widget with a fixed size using MediaQuery.size.height. When tapped animate the Column up to distance you want this to go, most likely the height of the Bottom Dialog Container.

Animating the y property of the Column should get this to work fine.